# Flickr API Oauth Error (Invalid Signature)

Tags: oauth, flickr

Hi have been having issues authenticating Flickr with OAuth, everytime i make a request i get the following Error.

`oauth_problem=signature_invalid&debug_sbs=GET&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fservices%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Facornsnoaks.dev%252Fadmin%252Foath%252Fflickr%26oauth_consumer_key%3D_MY_KEY_%26oauth_nonce%3D143594012893179%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1435940128%26oauth_version%3D1.0`

This is my URL
`https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token?oauth_nonce=143594012893179&oauth_timestamp=1435940128&oauth_consumer_key=_MY_KEY_&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=c3ec087c68536274f49e272179c321b8&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Facornsnoaks.dev%2Fadmin%2Foath%2Fflickr`

Please could i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Flickr API states that arguments should be sorted alphabetically? Did you do that before generating the HMAC-SHA1 signature for your call?